# Change a while from listning all items to list only x number of items (for maybe)

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone PLEASE help a newbie to change the while to list only x amount of items?

my end goal is to list 10 posts... not 1000s ;) lol

my code is:

```
<div class="partner-widget">
<br>
<?php 
$author_ID = get_query_var('author');
$t2 = 'cat= 666&author=' . $author_ID . '&order=ASC&showposts=-1';
query_posts($t2);
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><hr>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is actually change you `$t2` to limit your posts:

```
$t2 = 'cat= 666&author=' . $author_ID . '&order=ASC&showposts=10';
```

The complete could would then be like this:

```
<div class="partner-widget">
<br>
<?php 
$author_ID = get_query_var('author');
$t2 = 'cat= 666&author=' . $author_ID . '&order=ASC&showposts=10';
query_posts($t2);
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><hr>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: this is perfect. i found a way to do it using a   $counter++; but i don't like that...  your way is much better!   thank you!!!!

Comment: dumb question but - how are you sort out the non author posts in your code?  You lost me there...  Idid the t2 line to find only those posts. you removed it and it still works and better?  how and why?  THANK YOU

Comment: Glad I could help. Not sure if you used the `showposts` approach or went for the loop, but I had a little typo inside the loop. I change the answer to reflect the correct variable name. :)

Comment: Oh, I actually just edited the `$t2` line. If you change that, there's no need to change anything else. :)

Comment: you truly lost me.  can you please do me a giant favor.  and give me 100% correct code from start to finish.  you totally have me confused :(  what's weird is it is working yet the only code i have added is the second code box.  weird...

Comment: I've change the answer. See if that works better for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the limit parameter and limit the number of post you receive.

Comment: :)  how do i do that ;)